# xampp problem "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80"

Tags: apache

hey i have this problem when i installed xampp in ubuntu but when i try to type "http://localhost/dashboainfo.php" or "http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php" it comes with "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.  Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) rd/phpServer at localhost Port 80"

i've tried downloading it again and idk i've watched every that came in front of me but most of them were windows so i didn't have much videos to watch(using linux) and i was expecting to write a php code and runs normally(i'm still new with this)

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with php or mysql as the webserver cannot find the php file on the url you specified. You have to modify apache's settings or your url.

Comment: i have now a new problem "localhost refused to connect." i've tried to disable firewall but nothing changed and honestly idk what to do with this i've tried everythin and watched every video

Comment: @Shadow and do you have any idea how to do that like now the same thing happens to me when i type "http://localhost/dashboard/" "not found...."